# Using Exceptions in Transformer Monad

Tags: haskell

I have a question regarding use of Exceptions with a transformer stack.
I am a trying to develop some networking software, specifically implement
the GTP control protocol on S5 interface.
I am finding it difficult to get Exceptions work the transformer stack.

```
import Control.Monad (unless)
import Control.Exception
....
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
...
data GtpcModSt = GtpcModSt { sock             :: Socket
                       , rcvdBytes        :: BS.ByteString
                       , s5cTeidKey     :: Word32
                       ---- ....
                       } --deriving (Show)

type EvalGtpC a = (StateT GtpcModSt (ExceptT GtpcExceptions IO )) a
                  -- deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad) 



gtpcProcess = loop
       where loop = do
             rcvAndProcessGtpc   `catch` (\e -> do
                                      print "Exception handler"
                                      print (e :: SomeException))
            loop



 rcvAndProcessGtpc ::  EvalGtpC ()
 rcvAndProcessGtpc = do
                    sock <- gets sock
                    (msg, addr) <- liftIO $ recvFrom sock 1000
                    modify (\x -> x {rcvdBytes = msg, sndrAddr = addr})
                    processMsg
processMsg :: EvalGtpC ()
 processMsg = do
            --  validateSrc
           -----
          --....
            msg <- gets gtpMsg
            processGtpc $ msgType msg

 -- createSessionRequest
  processGtpc :: Word8 -> EvalGtpC ()
  processGtpc 32 = do
         myState@GtpcModSt {..} <- get
         .....

         sessParams <- return $ foldl ieInfo (SessionParams { imsi = Nothing
                              , mei = Nothing
                              , msisdn = Nothing
                              , senderFteidKey = Nothing
                              , senderIpV4Addr = Nothing
                              , senderIpV6Addr = Nothing
                              , pgwFteidKey      = Nothing
                              , pgwIpV4Addr   = Nothing
                              , pgwIpV6Addr   = Nothing
                              , apn           = Nothing
                              , paaPdnType    = Nothing
                              , pco           = Nothing
                              , bearerContext = []
                              , unDecodedIe   = []
                              , unSupportedIe = []
                              }) $ msgIeList gtpMsg


        ueApn <-return $ fromMaybe (throwE BadIe) (apn sessParams)
        apnCfg <- return $ fromMaybe (throw BadIe) $ Map.lookup ueApn apnProfile
        thisSndrFteidKey <-return $  fromMaybe (throw BadIe) (senderFteidKey sessParams)
```

I think that I should use `throwE`/`catchE` from `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`. However, `throwE` does not even compile when used with my transformer monad, as shown here:

```
apnCfg <- return $ fromMaybe (throw UnknownApn) $ Map.lookup ueApn apnProfile
```

Using `throw` from `Control.Exception` gets past the compilation stage but I am not sure it will work.
 Should I not be using Exception in a transformer monad that has `IO` as its base?

Answer (score 1):

> I think that I should use `throwE`/`catchE` from `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`. However, `throwE` does not even compile when used with my transformer monad, as shown here:
>
> ```
> apnCfg <- return $ fromMaybe (throw UnknownApn) $ Map.lookup ueApn apnProfile
> ```
>
> Using `throw` from `Control.Exception` gets past the compilation stage but I am not sure it will work.

This can be solved by following the types. In your do-block, we have:

```
-- I won't use the synonym here, for the sake of explicitness:
return :: a -> StateT GtpcModSt (ExceptT GtpcExceptions IO) a
```

The type of `throwE` is:

```
throwE :: Monad m => e -> ExceptT e m a
```

That being so, what you want is:

```
apnCfg <- maybe (lift $ throwE UnknownApn) return $ Map.lookup ueApn apnProfile
```

Firstly, you only need `return` if you aren't throwing (`maybe` is more convenient than `fromMaybe` for expressing that). Secondly, `throwE` produces an `ExceptT` computation that you need to `lift` to the outer, `StateT` layer. You can make the `lift` implicit by using *mtl* instead of *transformers* directly. To do that, change your imports from...

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
```

... to:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
import Control.Monad.Except
```

Then you can simply write (using the [`throwError`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html#v:throwError) method from `MonadError`):

```
apnCfg <- maybe (throwError UnknownApn) return $ Map.lookup ueApn apnProfile
```